# Memcache/Session with GAE and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, session

I have a JSP application what uses my GAE application. This JSP application is my mobile interface.

I would like to store in memcache (session) some values. I mean, when I open a JSP file, I call to my GAE application and I store this value.

I don't know how to archive it.

I have created this method (in my GAE Application) what is called from my JSP file but I get a null point on this.getThreadLocalRequest().

```
public void setTimezoneSession(String timezone){
    HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    // Here is where I try to set timezone in memcache (session)
    session.setAttribute("timezone", timezone);
}
```

In my JSP file I have called to AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "TimeZone.jsp",
    data: "tz_cliente=" + "Europe/Madrid",
    cache: false,
    success: function (msg) {}
});
```

TimeZone.jsp is this file:

```
<%
 // Here I get "Europe/Madrid" from AJAX.
 String tz = (String)request.getParameter("timezone_from_ajax");
 userService.setTimezoneSession(tz);
%>
```

What is wrong?

Thank you,
Diego.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable sessions for your App Engine app - they are disabled by default. In your appengine.xml file add:

```
  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
  <async-session-persistence enabled="true" />
```

Also, you can add this object in a session directly in your JSP without an AJAX call (if you have this data already available when you render a page):

```
 <%@ page session="true" %>
 ....
 <%
     HttpSession currentSession = request.getSession(true);
     currentSession.setAttribute("timezone", timezone);
 %>
```

Comment: I will try your solution. How can I get this data (timezone) in my server if I want to use it?

Comment: It depends on where you get this data from. If you store it in a datastore as a user preference, you can read it from the datastore directly in your jsp page. If you ask a user, you need to call a servlet after a user makes his choice (it does not have to be a jsp, by the way).

Comment: Well, thank you. That is what I will do. I'm gonna store on session the timezone and I can get it to do some operations.